# Suppose that $f$ has a measurable domain and is continuous except at a finite number of points. Is $f$ neccessarily measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Suppose that $f$ has a measurable domain and is continuous except at a finite number of points. Is $f$ neccessarily measurable?

Let $A$ be the set of points where $f$ is not continuous. Now since $A$ is finite we have that $m(A)=0$. Now as continuous maps are measurable if $E$ is the measurable domain, then $f$ defined on $E \setminus A$ is measurable.

Now I have a theorem that states

> For a measurable subset $D$ of $E$, $f$ is measurable on $E$ if and only if $f\mid_D$ and $f\mid_{E \setminus D}$ are both measurable.

$f\mid_{E \setminus A}$ being measurable follows from the fact that $f$ is continuous on $E \setminus A$, but how can I show that $f$ is measurable on $A$? I only know that the measure of $A$ is zero, but nothing about the behavior of $f$ there?

Comment: It doesn't matter, the answer is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Actually $f$ is Borel measurable.

Hints: We may as well take the domain to be the whole real line (by looking at $f\chi_D$). Let $f_n(x)=f(\frac {[nx]} n)$.  Check that each $f_n$ is Borel measurable. Let $g(x)= \lim \sup f_n(x)$. Then $g$ is Borel measurable and $f=g$ except at finite number of points. Can you finish? [Inverse images of a Borel set under $f$  and $g$ differ only by  a finite